# Memcache warnings

Tags: vps, drupal, memcache

I have installed memcache on a Dreamhost VPS (Debian GNU/Linux 5.0.9 (lenny) / memcached 1.4.10 ) for a Drupal site .

If for some reason the server needs rebooting, memcache is not restarted and Drupal spits out warnings about not being able to find memcache.

As mentioned in a previous [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/347621/memcache-basic-configuration), I'm using the following script to start & configure memcache

```
 sudo /etc/init.d/memcached
```

- Is it possible to call that script whenever the server is rebooted, if yes how?
- In case, the above is not possible or fails, how and where could I tell Drupal to bypass memcache.

`//pseudo code`

```
  if( memcache == null )
    bypass memcache
```

**EDIT**

@Jon Thanks for the template but it's still above my current scripting level!
Since I'm only running a single instance of memcache, here's what I have so far

```
 #! /bin/bash
 ### BEGIN INIT INFO
 # Provides:          memcached
 # Required-Start:    $syslog
 # Required-Stop:     $syslog
 # Should-Start:        $local_fs
 # Should-Stop:        $local_fs
 # Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
 # Default-Stop:      0 1 6
 # Short-Description:    memcached - Memory caching daemon
 # Description:        memcached - Memory caching daemon
 ### END INIT INFO#!/bin/sh -e

 memcached -u www-data -p 11211 -m 128 -d -l 127.0.0.1
```

It works fine, except that the script is not called after a server reboot! I need help to make this fit with the [template](http://programminglinuxblog.blogspot.com/2008/01/init-d-template-all.html) structure. I have no idea about the stop or restart command...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's on debian, then install memcached with `apt-get install memcached php5-memcached`. It will automatically populate init.d with the required start/stop script, so first remove your tampered memcached start script from init.d and the runlevels either by deleting it manually or give out `update-rc.d memcached remove`. Then do the apt-get install... And it will auto start/stop each and every time.

Comment: Installing memcache has been less than straightforward. I did try apt-get install, but memcache wasn't getting configured with the correct php version.

Comment: Well, If you compiled it from sources, then just remove it and use the packaged version. If you want to stick to your compiled memcached install, then get the debian memcached package and extract the init.d start/stop script from it.

Comment: http://packages.debian.org/lenny/memcached

Answer (score 0):

The command is:  **update-rc.d memcached defaults**

You can always man update-rc.d and get more details, but that should install the init script.

Sorry, can't answer for drupal.

Comment: taken from man update-rc.d : "System administrators are not encouraged to use update-rc.d to manage runlevels.  They should edit the links directly or use runlevel editors such as sysv-rc-conf and bum instead."

Comment: Sorry, unmarked as answered. I tried the update-rc.d command which seems to have updated a bunch of links but a few days later, the server was rebooted without calling the memcache script which runs fine if i call it directly as mentioned above...

Comment: Oh, if you can call it without a start/stop - then that's probably why.  Any script in /etc/init.d/ is supposed to be in a specific, service oriented format.  Take a look at [this template](http://programminglinuxblog.blogspot.com/2008/01/init-d-template-all.html)